# Does tomcat support secure websockets?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, websocket, tomcat7

Googling tomcat and websockets has revealed a number of pages on how to implement WebSockets in Tomcat, and in how to set up SSL/TLS in general, but it's not clear how to use both. In the  SSL howto (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration), a connector is created for use with HTTPS. Does a similar connector exist for WSS, and if so, what exact string values do I give to the attributes?

Comment: What was in the "number of pages on how to implement WebSockets in Tomcat"?

Comment: @EJP Unfortunately I can't links to the actual sites due to the new user restriction on posting links, but there were multiple tutorials on Tomcat Websocket implementations, without regard to secure connections. I'll edit later with the links to help the next person when I gain more rep. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any Tomcat `<Connector>` (including those that support that HTTPS) can accept websocket requests. Essentially, any combination of connector (BIO, NIO, AJP, both secure and non-secure) and protocol (HTTP, Comet, websocket) is supported.

Comment: Thank you. What I was missing is that WebSockets start as HTTP connections, and are then upgraded to a socket connection once established. Therefore, a separate connector is not needed.

Comment: Right, @JonathanPullano, there is no such thing as a "Websocket Connector" in Tomcat: any connector will do.

Answer (score 2):

Basically WebSocket doesn't have its own port like normal Socket implementation. Rather it uses the same port of server on which it deployed (e.g. 8080 for tomcat). So, If you make necessary changes on Connector to allow https, your websocket will automatically use https port.

I recommend to use Tomcat version 7.0.42 or higher which is stable with WebSocket.

Also note that - You need to use 'wss' instead of 'ws' for WebSocket on client side (browser/mobile etc).